# What do d3d, es2, j2d, null3d, and sw in the javafx prism package represent?

Tags: javafx

What do d3d, es2, j2d, null3d, and sw in the javafx prism package represent? As shown in the picture

[image: javafx prism package]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those packages represent implementations of different [graphics-pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline)

- d3d is short for [Direct3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct3D), part of DirectX
- es2 is for [OpenGL ES2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES)
- j2d represents the [Java 2D API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/spec/j2d-intro.html)
- null3d - not sure but probably a dummy-implementation for development/testing
- sw - software pipeline